# Java List with each element having 2 values

Tags: java

I have a requirement to have a list, where each element must have 2 values.
I want to know what would be the best way to implement it.
Should I use `HashSet`, `HashMap` or anything else ?

The list should look like this -

`<Elem1_val1, Elem1_val2>, <Elem2_val1, Elem2_val2>, <Elem3_val1, Elem3_val2>,  ....
<Elemn_val1, Elemn_val2>,`

The important point here is that val1 and val2 belong to same Element.
What would be a good way to implement this?

**UPDATE:**

1. Can anyone comment about implementing - `List<Map.Entry<ClassA, ClassB>>`
2. I don't want to have new class, because I just want to store 2 objects which have 
   some co-relation together in one list.

Thanks !

Comment: You know the difference between a `HashSet` and a `HashMap` right?

Comment: Yes, I know the difference. However, I am not able to decide for this kind of requirement, what I should use exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

how about creating a class that has two elements and create a `List` of that class

```
class DataHelper{
  String element1;
  String element2;
}
```

Comment: I don't actually want to introduce a new class, even if this is a valid solution.

Comment: You're working in an OOP language. Writing your own class here is astronomically more appropriate than using a less specific data type.

Comment: It is because, I don't think it can be a new class. There are already a lot of classes in my code. And I just want to maintain 2 objects which have some co-relation together in a list.

Comment: @RajTendulkar. In that case, you should stop coding in OOP.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a lot of classes, provided that each of them does something useful and distinct. Using `Map.Entry` is OK but  doesn't allow you to add any other behaviour (such as validation) to your pair.

Comment: @DNA, suppose that I implement the class with 2 elements as shown by Jigar, won't it be over-design? Because I won't have any member functions for such class.

Comment: this is called POJO (Plain Old Java Object) and ther's nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 10):

The best is to use a List with a class like [Pair](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-sdk/com/android/util/Pair.java.htm) as elements.

If you don't know the classes of your vals, you would declare it as

```
List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<Pair>();
```

If you know the classes of your objects, you can declare your list as

```
List<Pair<ClassA, ClassB>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<ClassA, ClassB>>();
```

Here's [an example of a generic Pair implementation](http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/8-java/10-java-pair-class).

Comment: Ah, I think this is great idea. I got my answer. I should implement it as - `List<Map.Entry<ClassA, ClassB>>`

Comment: I don't think so. You shouldn't use a class like that which is designed for a specific purpose, not yours. I suggest you use the generic class I link too or a more specific one like what was suggered by Jigar.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not mind using apache: You could also use

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair<L, R>
```

or

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair<L, R>
```

refer to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html for more information about these classes.